# Convert BBCode using Regular expressions

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-2, bbcode

I am building a custom discussion board for a website. (The website does need a custom one. :) ) What I am trying to do is use regular expressions to take a [b] and turn into  at the output. Then also the other style [img]example.jpg[/img] and output <\img src= "example.jpg">. But so far everything I have tried does not seem to be working. Does anyone have any examples of how this would work?

Comment: And I tagged it correctly but I forgot to mention that I am using asp.net mvc2

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far.   The we can help you produce a working regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brief solution in perl is

```
s/\[b\]([^\[]*)\[\/b\]/<b>$1<\/b>/g;
s/\[img\]([^\[]*)\[\/img\]/<img src="$1" \/>/g;
```

To elaborate this solution in php would be:

```
<?
$text = 'enter your text here';
$text = preg_replace('/\[b\]([^\[]*)\[\/b\]/','<b>$1<\/b>',$text);
$text = preg_replace('/\[img\]([^\[]*)\[\/img\]/','<img src="$1" \/>',$text);
print "$text";  // print new text
?>
```

To be more precise in perl you can use:

```
$text = ' text [b]tucny[/b] je [b]u[/b]rcite [img]dobre.gif[/img] dalsi';
$text =~ s/\[b\]([^\[]*)\[\/b\]/<b>$1<\/b>/g;
$text =~ s/\[img\]([^\[]*)\[\/img\]/<img src="$1" \/>/g;
print $text;
```

Jakub

Comment: BTW the img tag you have mentioned in your question is not correct I think you ment <img src= "example.jpg" /> instead of <\img src= "example.jpg">

Comment: Yes I did. And sorry for the delay in replying. Your answer worked very well.